# How to Display error message when record not found in database

Tags: html, jsp

How to search records in table . i want to search data using id. if that id is available in database then open edit.jsp if not exist then display any error  message. i want to use jsp technology.

Search.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hicourt.css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



</script>



<body onLoad="randomString()">
  <form name="f1" method="post"  action="edit.jsp"> 
   <div id="wrapper">

   <div id="banner">

   </div>
   <div  id="navigation" align="center">
 Search Registration Number

   </div>

   <div id="content_area">



       <p class="contact"><label for="name"><span style="font-weight:bold">EDIT</span></label> 
                <input id="id" name="id" placeholder="Advocate Reg Number" required=""  type="text"> 
                 </p>

    <div style="text-align:center">  
     <input name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="10" value="EDIT" align="middle"type="submit">
      </div>   </div>


   <div id="footer">
   </div>
   </div>



   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Post related codes only. Don't paste all codes here. Also, tidy up your codes.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Re post the question in a better way....

Comment: This could be useful [Check here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jdbc-tutorial)